# FactoryBot on model with unique validation ... can't rerun tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using FactoryBot for the first time and am having an issue with testing if it can create a valid user.

My `test/factories/users.rb` file is:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "email#{n}@email.com" }
    sequence(:username) { |n| "first-name#{n} last-name#{n}" }
    sequence(:password) { |n| "password#{n}" }
  end
end
```

My test is:

```
it 'should test that the User factory is valid' do
    expect(FactoryBot.build :user).to be_valid
end
```

I'm using devise for my User model, and I am getting the following error the second time I run my test:

```
Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Are you using something like the [DatabaseCleaner gem](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) to manage cleaning up your test databases? The description of your problem sounds less like a FactoryBot issue and more a cleanup issue. Each run will start the sequence over at 1, so if it's failing on the second run the problem is likely due to not cleaning/truncating the test database prior to executing your suite.

Comment: No I'm not using any db cleaner gem.... I will investigate